# CoffeeScript mixin doesn't work

Tags: coffeescript

I found this example of mixins in [coffeescript faq](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/FAQ#classes) but it seems like it doesn't work.

Am I missing something here?

```
extend = (obj, mixin) ->
  for name, method of mixin
    obj[name] = method

include = (klass, mixin) ->
  extend klass.prototype, mixin

class Button
  onClick: -> alert "click"

class Events
include Button, Events

(new Events).onClick()

# => Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Events> has no method 'onClick'
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQwHa/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the fact that onClick is defined on the prototype of Button,
and that you did not set the arguments with the right order in the include function

```
extend = (obj, mixin) ->
  for name, method of mixin
    obj[name] = method

include = (klass, mixin) ->
  extend klass.prototype, mixin

class Button
  onClick: -> alert "click"

class Events
include Events,Button.prototype

(new Events).onClick()
```

[see the "fiddle"](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aextend%20%3D%20%28obj%2C%20mixin%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20for%20name%2C%20method%20of%20mixin%0A%20%20%20%20obj%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20method%0A%0Ainclude%20%3D%20%28klass%2C%20mixin%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20extend%20klass.prototype%2C%20mixin%0A%0Aclass%20Button%0A%20%20onClick%3A%20-%3E%20alert%20%22click%22%0A%0Aclass%20Events%0Ainclude%20Events%2CButton.prototype%0A%0A%28new%20Events%29.onClick%28%29)

So the mixin snippet works pretty well.